# Hook to PowerShell runspace closing outside of cmdlet lifetime?

Tags: powershell

I'm writing some binary (C#) PowerShell cmdlets that wrap the functionality of a 3rd-party library that requires you to instantiate and destroy a context object. This library has a couple of quirks:

1. It needs to have its context closed before the process exits, or else it crashes the process loudly at that time.
2. It doesn't like to have contexts instantiated and destroyed repeatedly in a short timeframe, or it starts producing internal errors.

Due to #2, instantiating and destroying the library within each cmdlet is too short of a timespan, so I need to keep the library alive as long as possible. Thus I'm planning on storing the library context in the PowerShell runspace's session state so that it lasts for the duration of the runspace (i.e. the lifetime of the interactive shell).

But by #1, I still need to dispose the library before the runspace closes. This happens, as I understand, outside the lifetime of my cmdlets. Is there any way I can hook to the runspace's closing to destroy my library? I can do so within the cmdlet process via the `Runspace.StateChanged` event, but is there a way to ensure my library gets closed when the runspace closes, even after my cmdlet process is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hook the `Runspace.StateChanged` event, your cmdlet doesn't need to be executing for the event handler to invoked.  Just put the code to close the library in the event handler for this event when the `RunspaceStateEventArgs` indicates `Closing`.

Another option is to create a wrapper object around the library that implements a finalizer.  Inside the finalizer (or Dispose() method if you implement IDisposable) close the library.  So when the library wrapper is created it is presumably stashed in a static somewhere so the object isn't collected (and finalized i.e. library closed) by virtue of the object being GC'd.  Later when the PowerShell process shuts down it will attempt to finalize all objects that are still hanging around.

Yet another option is to require the end user to new-foosession to open the library and get a handle to it and then later use remove-foosession to allow the user to explicitly close the library.  You could still use the finalizer approach above in case the use forgets to call remove-foosession.